# value in href with computed property is not dynamic

Tags: vue.js, nuxtjs

Basically, I want a dynamic link on my `a href` based on the code. Where I want my link to be to example2.com when the website using my NuxtJS code is example1.com.. However, it will always get linked to `/` instead of example2.com.. It is really weird as it can clearly be seen in Vue Inspection Tool and in `{{ backHref }}` that it is already returning example2.com.. However it does not reflect in `:href`

```
/* eslint-disable vue/no-v-html */
<template>
  <div class="h-100 bg-ededed">
    <a :href="backHref">{{ backHref }}</a>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import { mapState } from 'vuex'

export default {
  meta: { noFooter: true },

  computed: {
    ...mapState({
      chatRooms: (state) => state.chat.chatRooms
    }),
    backHref() {
      let link
      if (this.chatRooms.length === 1) {
        console.log(`this.isExample: ${this.isExample}`)
        if (this.isExample) {
          console.log('went here 1')
          link = 'https://example2.com'
        } else {
          console.log('went here 2')
          link = '/'
        }
      } else {
        link = '/chat/'
      }
      console.log(
        `this.addChannelCodeLink(link): ${this.addChannelCodeLink(link)}`
      )
      return this.addChannelCodeLink(link)
    },
    getDomain() {
      let host
      if (process.client && window) {
        host = window.location.host
      }
      return host
    },
    isExample() {
      return this.getDomain ? this.getDomain.includes('example1.com') : false
    }
  },
  methods: {
    addChannelCodeLink(link) {
      if (this.$route.query.r) {
        link += `?r=${this.$route.query.r}`
      }
      return link
    }
  }
}
</script>

<style lang="scss" scoped></style>
```

`Console.log` will be something like this:

```
- While in SSR
this.isExample: false
went here 2
this.addChannelCodeLink(link): /

- In Client
this.isExample: true
went here 1
this.addChannelCodeLink(link): http://example2.com
```

Comment: What do you get in t the console log?

Comment: went here 2 in SSR
Then went here 1 in Client

Comment: The "this.addChanneCodeLink" is missing?

Comment: What do you mean? The example code is working fine. The problem is the value of `backHref ` in `:href` remains `/`

Comment: What I meant is that it would help seeing the complete console log.

Comment: I just updated my question regarding console.logs

Comment: I assume it because you fetch the domain from the window object, which is not accessible by Nuxt Sever, so it always defaults to `/` in server side

Comment: Don't know if you still need help with this, but if you do, can you provide a https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example ?  I tried to run your code, but I got "Cannot read property 'state' of undefined ".